# How to get SQL Server CE TableAdapter to commit to database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

VS2008 project.  Created local database (SSCE).  Created dataset with tableadapter.  Dragged dataset and tableadapter to the form so I can reference it in code.

New records successfully add to the dataset but will not commit back to the database.  Gives no error or clue why it won't work.

TableAdapter insert statement was created automatically and is parameterized (@p1, @p2, etc.), but I am trying to avoid those parameter.add statements as I want to be able to use a field-by-field format without having to essentially repeat the schema of my database in code with parameter.add statements.  Command object and INSERT statements work fine, but then you always have to construct an INSERT statement -- a pain if they're complicated.  I want something as simple as working with a ADO recordset, but in .NET.

I know the last statement with the update is wrong without the parameters, but looking for an alternative method.

What can I do to accomplish the following without parameter.add statements?

```
DocsTableAdapter1.Fill(Documents1.Docs)
Debug.Print("Starting Row Count is: " & Documents1.Docs.Count.ToString)
Dim dr As DataRow = Documents1.Docs.NewRow
dr("Name") = "John Smith"
dr("Reference") = "My new reference code"
Documents1.Docs.Rows.Add(dr)
Debug.Print("New Row Count is: " & Documents1.Docs.Count.ToString)
DocsTableAdapter1.Update(Documents1.Docs)
```